# Can I test a dynamic html view using javascript in the chrome console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, automated-tests

Let's say I'm testing an angular app but it's way too time-consuming for me to learn the codebase and write code for it. I'm purely testing the view. Is it possible to use javascript in the chrome console to test the view?

Like if I want to test whether or not clicking on a button renders a view with a certain element with class 'class1', can I do this?

```
$(".class").click();
if ($(".class1") != null){console.log("class 1 is here!")};
history.back();
```

Is there any standardized way to do this?

Comment: Yes that can be done. Be sure that the webpage has jQuery (it looks like you want to use it). Also the correct way to test if `.class1` exists is `if ($(".class1").length){console.log("class 1 is here!")};`

Comment: You could also use something like Tampermonkey to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You're describing either an end-to-end test (or integration test). You can do that using a framework like protractor:
https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/